# Action Mailer Missing Template error unless body is specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

Hello I am getting a missing template error in my code for a contact form I am making despite the files being in what I believe to be the proper place and everything else exactly like the action mailer basics tutorial I followed. I even remade the mailer and it still won't work.

**contactmailer**

```
class ContactMailer < ApplicationMailer

default from: 'test@example.com'

layout 'mailer'

def notify(contact)
    @contact = contact
    mail(to: 'text@example.com', subject: 'Notification')
end
end
```

**contact controller**

```
def create

  @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)  

  if @contact.save 

    ContactMailer.notify(@contact).deliver_now
    redirect_to root_path

  else
    render :new

  end


end
```

**views/contact_mailer/notify.text.erb**
    Test

**config/development.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
# Settings specified here will take precedence over those in      config/application.rb.

# In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
# every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
# since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
config.cache_classes = false

# Do not eager load code on boot.
config.eager_load = false

# Show full error reports and disable caching.
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

# Don't care if the mailer can't send.
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

# Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
config.active_support.deprecation = :log

# Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

# Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
# This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
# number of complex assets.
config.assets.debug = true

# Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all    assets,
# yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
config.assets.digest = true

# Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
# Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
# Raises helpful error messages.
config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
# SMTP settings for gmail
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
:address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
:port                 => 587,
:domain               => "gmail.com",
:enable_starttls_auto => true,
:user_name            => 'example@gmail.com',
:password             => 'examplepassword',
:authentication       => "plain",
:ssl =>    false
:openssl_verify_mode  => 'none'
}
end
```

IF i add a body param to mail it works but doesn't work otherwise.

**EDIT: ERROR I RECEIVE**

```
ContactMailer#notify: processed outbound mail in 31.9ms
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 61ms (ActiveRecord: 3.7ms)

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template layouts/mailer with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :slim, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/ubuntu/workspace/autosales2/app/views"
):
  app/mailers/contact_mailer.rb:7:in `notify'
  app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:15:in `create'


  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (11.1ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (5.2ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/missing_template.html.erb within rescues/layout (93.5ms)
```

Comment: You should add the error with backtrace here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have plain text template in place. What about the `.html.erb`?

Try this code to limit your mailer to only sending plain text emails if that's what you want:

```
def notify(contact)
    @contact = contact
    mail(to: 'text@example.com', subject: 'Notification') do |format|
        format.text
    end
end
```

Otherwise, if you want html emails, provide their template as well.

**UPDATE**

From the error text it is apparent that the mailer's layout template cannot be found. You have this in your mailer:

```
layout 'mailer'
```

This means any particular action template will be rendered as part of the mentioned layout template. Therefore you need this layout template in place. You can see that the mailer expects it to be called `layouts/mailer` and looks for it in `app/views`, which makes it

```
app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb # for html emails
app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb # for plain text emails
```

If you do not need a common layout for the emails, you can just remove the `layout 'mailer'` line and it should work.

Comment: I tried this as well without luck and have an html file in place as well. I read somewhere that it could be that the spring gem is loading things in some weird order, do you know how this would possibly be fixed?

Comment: Please add the error that you're getting, complete with backtrace.

Comment: Missing template layouts/mailer with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :slim, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/home/ubuntu/workspace/autosales2/app/views"

Comment: Please add the error as part of your question, not as a comment. See my updated answer.

Comment: yes I have two files notify.html.erb and notify.text.erb in app/views/contact_mailer which is where it's looking but doesn't seem to find them